# Help with finding the volume of the region: $y=\ln(3x), y=2, y=5, x=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do to properly set this up.

Original problem:

$$y=\ln(3x), y=2, y=5, x=0$$

$$A=\pi r^2$$
$$A=\pi(\ln 3x)^2$$

So I figured I needed the endpoints of this graph so I solved for the two values of $x$

$$\ln(3x)=2$$
$$3x=2e$$
$$x=\frac{2e}{3}$$

And the other:

$$\ln(3x)=5$$
$$3x=5e$$
$$x=\frac{5e}{3}$$

But from here I'm totally lost.  I'm not sure which values I use for my intervals.  Please help!

Comment: The _first_ thing to do is to draw a diagram.

Comment: Which line are you revolving this region around? (You're leaving out part of the problem.)

Comment: I drew a diagram but I don't know how to post it on here.  I also have to rotate it about the $y-axis$

Comment: Since you're revolving around the y-axis, your limits will be in terms of y, and you have to solve your original equation for x in terms of y.

Comment: @user84413 OK so I go from $2,5$ and integrate $ln(3x)$

Comment: You still need to solve for x in $y=\ln(3x)$, and then set up your expression for the area of a typical slice before you integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we want to express the function as a function of $y$, the variable with respect to which we are integrating.

$$y=\ln(3x) \iff e^y = 3x \iff \frac{e^y}{3} = x$$

The bounds of integration, since we are rotating about the $y$ axis, are from $y = 2$ to $y = 5$.

$$\pi \int_2^5 \left(\frac {e^y}{3}\right)^2 \,dy$$

Comment: Why am I solving for $x$?  I'm sorry, but I don't understand this part.

Comment: Because we are rotating the graph about the $y$ axis, so radius is measured as *horizontal distance* between $x = 0$ and $x(y)$. I.e., we're integrating over horizontal slices of area.

Comment: $\color{blue}{@amWhy}+_+$

Comment: @amWhy: very clear as usual +1

Answer (score 1):

Rotating about the $y$ axis, you have to integrate annular washers over $y$, so you need $x(y)$.  Draw a picture.  The integral you will end up with is

$$\pi \int_2^5 dy \, \left ( \frac{e^{10}}{9} - \frac{e^{2 y}}{9}\right )$$